# Add matrix with all similar value in one rows on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's `X`

```
Id  Jakarta Bandung
1        10      40
2        20      50
3        30      60
```

Here's dataframe 'y`

```
Jakarta      Bandung
     11           12
```

And `Xplusy`

```
Id  Jakarta Bandung
1        21      52
2        31      62
3        41      72
```

How to code `Xplusy`?

Comment: `Id` is index or column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice `y` to Series using [`iloc[0]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) and [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

If `Id` is the index:

```
x.add(y.iloc[0])
# or
x.add(y.squeeze())
```

Else, if `Id` is a column:

```
x.set_index('Id').add(y.iloc[0]).reset_index()
```

Or use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
x.add(y.squeeze().reindex(x.columns, fill_value=0))
```

output:

```
   Id  Jakarta  Bandung
0   1       21       52
1   2       31       62
2   3       41       72
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Id` is index use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) witt select first row of `Y` for `Series` by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
X = X.add(Y.iloc[0])
print (X)
    Jakarta  Bandung
Id                  
1        21       52
2        31       62
3        41       72
```

---

If `Id` is first column select all columns without first:

```
X.iloc[:, 1:] = X.iloc[:, 1:].add(Y.iloc[0])
print (X)
   Id  Jakarta  Bandung
0   1       21       52
1   2       31       62
2   3       41       72
```

Or get all columns same in both DataFrames by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
cols = X.columns.intersection(Y.columns)
X[cols] = X[cols].add(Y.iloc[0])
print (X)
   Id  Jakarta  Bandung
0   1       21       52
1   2       31       62
2   3       41       72
```